# Intent not being received

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities involved in this question. The first one the user inputs data on a simple form style layout. It then should save the 4 pieces of data to an intent (putextra) and startActivity(intent).

The second should retrieve the data and have them ready to be loaded in to arrays. When i run the debug, the intent from activity1 successfully holds the values; however, activity2 says the intent is null.. I'm unsure of what is happening in between.

ACTIVITY1

```
EditText editDebtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtName);
    debtName = editDebtName.getText().toString();

    EditText editDebtAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtAmount);
    String debtAmountStr = editDebtAmount.getText().toString();

    EditText editDebtRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtRate);
    String debtRateStr = editDebtRate.getText().toString();

    EditText editDebtPayment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtPayment);
    String debtPaymentStr = editDebtPayment.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, DebtList.class);
    i.putExtra("newDebtName", debtName);
    i.putExtra("newDebtAmount", debtAmountStr);
    i.putExtra("newDebtRate", debtRateStr);
    i.putExtra("newDebtPayment", debtPaymentStr);

    startActivity(i);
```

ACTIVITY2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.debtlist);

    String[] debtName = new String[10];
    String[] debtAmount = new String[10];
    String[] debtRate = new String[10];
    String[] debtPayment = new String[10];
    int trigger = 5;

    SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("chaosdatasnowball", 0);

    debtName = getFromSharedPreference("debtNames", this.getApplicationContext());
    debtAmount = getFromSharedPreference("debtAmounts", this.getApplicationContext());
    debtRate = getFromSharedPreference("debtRates", this.getApplicationContext());
    debtPayment = getFromSharedPreference("debtPayments", this.getApplicationContext());

    trigger = sharedPref.getInt("trigger", trigger);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    debtName[trigger] = extras.getString("newDebtName");
    debtAmount[trigger] = extras.getString("newDebtAmount");
    debtRate[trigger] = extras.getString("newDebtRate");
    debtPayment[trigger] = extras.getString("newDebtPayment");
```

There are no error messages being throw out either. What I'm trying to determine is.. why is my intent not being received..?

Comment: The Intent is null, or the extras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem cause by this code

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("chaosdatasnowball", 0);
    debtName = getFromSharedPreference("debtNames", this.getApplicationContext());
    debtAmount = getFromSharedPreference("debtAmounts", this.getApplicationContext());
    debtRate = getFromSharedPreference("debtRates", this.getApplicationContext());
    debtPayment = getFromSharedPreference("debtPayments", this.getApplicationContext());
```

Because i test without above code, activity2 still receive bundle value. If you try without above code and still have that problem, you should try to debug & show all values of string array to determine problem again.